# find all links with a specific data attribute and replace the anchor text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# string contains random HTML code.
How can I get all the links with this specific data- attribute "data-special-attr" and replace all the links' text with the attribute's value. Finally, remove the attribute.

for example:
before:

```
<a href="http://example.com" style='class' data-foo='' data-special-attr="new text1">old text1</a>
```

after:

```
<a href="http://example.com" style='class' data-foo=''>new text1</a>
```

I need to run this method on a string that contains multiple links with this specific attr and other html code.

Thanks

Comment: $('a[data-special-attr]').val($(this).attr('data-special-attr')).removeAttr('data-special-attr');

Comment: The html code is a C# string. I'm looking for a regex replace solution

Comment: i would rather recommend use htmlagilitypack as it will be more usefull if you need further manipulation ahead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Right Way" aside, regexes are fun:

```
string sample = @"<a href=""http://example.com"" style='class' data-foo='' data-special-attr=""new text1"">old text1</a>";
string output = Regex.Replace(sample, @"<([^>]+) data-special-attr=""([^""]+)"">[^<]*</a>", "<$1>$2</a>");

Console.WriteLine(sample);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

I'm assuming there's no attributes after the data-special-attr.  When searching for matching quotes or '<' / '>' I like to use (eg) /"([^"]+)"/ rather than /"(.+)"/

Comment: thanks but what if I don't know if there is more after data-special-attr.

Comment: adding in a ([^>]*) will match zero-or-more anything that isn't a '>'.  Place it before the '>' and use $1, $2 and $3 in your replacement text.

That should be pretty easy for you to do, but let me know if you have trouble.